# How to build app compliant with Google Play 64-bit requirement?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

After I upload the APK to play store I got the following warning. What changes should I make to release an APK build with flutter SDK to meet the 64-bit requirement?

The warning message:
[image]

Comment: A solution is now provided by the flutter team (version > 1.7.12). See my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56817004/3567888

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Edit/Update:` Google has released Flutter 1.7.8+hotfix.3 in stable channel, which makes easy to build an app for release.

Now you have two options to build :

1. App bundle (preferred)
2. APK

> Generating App Bundle

Run   `flutter build appbundle`

This will create `<app dir>/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab` 

T app bundle contains your Dart code and the Flutter runtime compiled for `armeabi-v7a (32-bit)` and `arm64-v8a (64-bit)`.

Now you can upload this app bundle to google play.

> Build an APK

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

This command results in two APK files:

```
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
```

Removing the --split-per-abi flag results in a fat APK that contains your code compiled for all the target ABIs. Such APKs are larger in size than their split counterparts, causing the user to download native binaries that are not applicable to their device’s architecture.

> If you haven't upgraded to flutter 1.7 Below solution should still
>   work.

You need to build two apk and upload them together. one for 32 and another for 64 bit.

This is what worked for me I am on flutter v1.5.4-hotfix.2

First, run `flutter build apk --release` and upload the apk file

Then increase the version and build number in pubspec.yml file and run

```
flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm64
```

Upload this new apk and start rollout.

Good luck

Answer (score 20):

Guys they changed new policies for `64-bit` architectures. So please put this code in your gradle

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

for e.g.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stefan what issue you are facing?

Comment: I added the line to the config and run `flutter build apk` and uploaded the apk to google play. The same error from the google play console appeared...

Comment: Works for me only after switching to flutter master channel.

Comment: Do you have a solution without using flutter?

Comment: Flutter is not supporting x86 so don't add that. Check here: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was

```
flutter build appbundle --release
```

Upload the appbundle file

Then increase the version and build number in the pubspec.yml file and run

```
flutter build appbundle --release --target-platform=android-arm64
```

Upload also this new appbundle.

Then the play store accepted my release

Answer (score 3):

I finally was able to fix this by adding this to build.gradle

```
 ndk {
        abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
    }
}

splits {
    abi {
        include  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
    }
 }
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "arm64-v8a":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
 }
```

There is not a lot of clear documentation on this, I happened to run into this by scouring the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is a new better solution provided by the futter team.
You need to use the new **flutter version 1.7.12**. (my setup)

```
Flutter 1.7.12-pre.40 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 3badcf51a4 (13 hours ago) • 2019-06-28 15:14:03 -0700
Engine • revision e96900df2f
Tools • Dart 2.4.0
```

Then you can build your (single) app bundle for x86 and x64 with this command.
`flutter build appbundle`

Additional you can add `--release --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64`. But this might cause a broken app...

Answer (score 1):

Use latest master channel of Flutter. 
`flutter build apk` will result into a fat APK containing support for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

To create 32-bit and 64-bit APK separately, use `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` command

Comment: Works for me only after switching to flutter master channel.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2 appbundle currently targets android-arm which builds only 32bit native code (`flutter build appbundle -h`). To change this run `flutter build appbundle --target-platform=android-arm64` to change the default target.

Comment: with Flutter 1.7.8+hotfix.3 on stable channel, If I build app bundle now will it gonna have 32&64bit both or I need to build it using master channel only?

Answer (score 0):

I built mine with this code and i still get the error.

flutter build appbundle --target-platform=android-arm64

Comment: why not just use flutter build appbundle?

Comment: I’ve tried every possible command including that one , same error

Answer (score 0):

if you use **Android Studio**

just go to **Build -> Flutter -> Build App Bundle** to replace it with apk when uploaded to google play

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your android/app/build.gradle file

`ndk {
  abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86','x86_64'
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I try all answers and Its stay shows the same issue.

I tried to add this line as the most answers:

```
ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64',  'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
```

but it's not solved.

**what's** **solved** **my** **problem?**

just you need to add "**armeabi**" to the last code and it will be like:

```
ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
```

this solution saved my day and I uploaded my app bundle successfully!