# Upload to Play Store 64 bit warning

Tags: flutter

So I have been googling this and it seems that when runing "flutter build appbundle" it should include both 32 bit and 64 bit in the app bundle, but when uploading the release "app.aab" I get the warning from Play Store saying that this bundle only includes 32 bit code and I can not continue.

"flutter doctor" gives me "Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-GB)"

Comment: You'll need to enable the `arm64-v8a` target. This might be missing from your gradle config file. Maybe you can post this as well?

Comment: My android/app/build.gradle or gradle.properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can ignore this warning as of now and after june flutter will start including 32 & 64 bit inside a single app bundle. If you really want to enable this read this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-announce/oIzwT9EDczc

**UPDATE**
Solved by the flutter team in version 1.7.12. Compare this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56817004/3567888).

Answer (score 0):

Add in you app/build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```

And run flutter build apk --release. Send apk files.