# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement error still after adding libraries

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am uploading a video editor app on play store that has libraries with some native code. So I made it compatible for 64bit by adding this to gradle.

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

Adding it still problem is not solved . When I upload on playstore it still gives 64bit error. This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.maam.videoeditor"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

}
```

I have added 64bit line in gradle but on uploading 64bit not compliant error shows. Kindly guide on solving this problem.

Comment: not being compliant is not something that changes by adding libraries. not being compliant means you should change either the library that is not compliant, or the one that causes it to be not compliant

Comment: Check 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid' if it has 64 bit version. I guess that's your problem

Comment: Yes the library is fine as I already uploaded an app with same lib before with 64bit code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build app compliant with Google Play 64-bit requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982981/how-to-build-app-compliant-with-google-play-64-bit-requirement)

Comment: The problem with this was that the library had no support for x64 art. For anyone having same problem in future should find an alternate library that has support for x64 art. To check if any library has support for x64 check this.   https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: My app uses an old library that is not in x64. When I did it, there wasn't even an App Bundle yet. Can someone help me by telling me how to get around the x64 issue or how do I configure my app for the App Bundle? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Osama: First of all, please check if your apk file have library in 64 bit. There are many way to do this:
- Use Analyze Apk function of Android Studio (for more detail, please refer: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)
- Archive your apk file and check inside that folder.
If your app doesn't has folder "arm64-v8a" it mean your app still not versioned up to 64 bit.

About your requirement, if you want your app is support 64 bit architecture, you must also version up your native library (.so file) to 64 bit.

About your code:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'"
```

I don't recommend you add this unless you use AppBundle new feature of Android Studio.
Because when you use this, there will be 4 new apk file created for each architecture.
And if you upload the file of arm64-v8a architecture, the error will disappear but it will announce you that your apk is support less device than previous release because it cannot support 32 bit device.

There are 2 possible solution for this problem:

1. Put all library file to your apk file, it will make your app bigger but it will allow your app to support every device.
2. Apply AppBundle for your project. For more detail about this, please check this link: https://android.jlelse.eu/a-practical-guide-to-android-app-bundle-for-beginners-7e8d93831828

Comment: The libraries I use do not have an x64 version. I've tried several things but I still can't update it in the store. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

```
android {    
    compileSdkVersion 29    
    defaultConfig {    
        -----    
        -----    
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'    
        ndk {    
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'    
        }    
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"    
    }    

    packagingOptions {    
            exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libvudroid.so'    
            exclude 'lib/x86/libvudroid.so'    
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libvudroid.so'    
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be enhanced by some explanation for how it addresses the question.

Comment: only excluding 32 bit helped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following to your android/app/build.gradle file:

```
android {    
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        ....
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
}
```

add the following to your android/build.gradle file:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                .....
                .....

                packagingOptions {
                    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
                    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
                    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
                    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is to include the 64-bit architecture.
If not this, then you might need to create app bundle and then upload

Comment: that did it for me ... thanks Harshit

Answer (score 0):

From my case, what the google support team replied, it is due to an older (legacy) release build uploaded (which does not comply the 64-bit requirement) where it is being included at the 'previous release' section while uploading the new application.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example, a quote of the reply might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

If you upload your apk on alpha version and this error will be show, so please check if any exiting apk is live or not if not live so please remove your old apk and upload your new apk.

I think your problem is solve.

Answer (score -2):

I have faced with same situation...
My application wasnot game neither cross-platform  application...
I have faced with this situation...
Solutions was simple... One of my app dependecy(library that implemented by gradle) was using ndk...
After I remove it, problem gone.

Comment: im facing this situation. i didnt found any ndk in my app. how you did it? can you help me pls?

Comment: The Libraries that you use in your app ( Gradle implemantation) might be use NDK