# React Native: This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

When I published my `React Native App` in `Google Play` I got this error:

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 9 and 24.
>
> Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

[image]

How can I fix this Error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build app compliant with Google Play 64-bit requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982981/how-to-build-app-compliant-with-google-play-64-bit-requirement)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `android/app/build.gradle` file:

```
abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
```

Specifically, you need to add the 64-bit ABI for whatever 32-bit ABI you already had in the list.

Comment: Do I put this inside the object `defaultConfig => ndk  { ... }`

Comment: Yes! Although, if you have dependencies that embed native code, you might also have to upgrade them. Best way to know is to look at your APK with android Studio APK Analyzer, to see which 32 & 64 bits libs you have and make sure both lists are the same

Answer (score 0):

React Native will support 64 bit for android starting version 0.59

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814#issuecomment-457688789