# How to resolve Google Play 64 bit error in AAB release?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, 64-bit, google-play-console

I was trying to upload the apk since 2 days. Every time I upload the apk I get the 64 bit error. I know there are other questions on Stackoverflow asking the same thing. But most of them saying the solution for flutter.

[image]

As per the [Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) I used [APK Analyze](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#apk-analyzer) and found that there are .so files in my project.

Based on documentation I added **`ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`**. But Still I get the same error.

Please check my build.gradle code.

```
android {


compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXXXX"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 237
    versionName "3.3.20"
    multiDexEnabled true

    //ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64' - not worked
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}

flavorDimensions "default"

buildTypes {

    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

productFlavors {
    production {
        applicationId 'com.XXXXX'
    }

    staging {
        applicationId 'com.XXXXX.staging'
    }
}

// Add this block and enable/disable the parameters as follows
bundle {
    density {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    abi {
        // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
        enableSplit true
    }
    language {
        // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
        // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
        enableSplit false
    }
}}
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

After signed bundle apk creation the **.so** files are showing same in armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64 folders.

Comment: any external SDKs or libraries using ? have module?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I am using an external library & two aar gradle lib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build app compliant with Google Play 64-bit requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982981/how-to-build-app-compliant-with-google-play-64-bit-requirement)

Comment: @TomazMazej: I don't want Flutter solutions

Comment: Just a note to say that while the OP's link to google's documentation may be broken, their own link to that page in the play console is also broken. Having searched, I think this is now the correct link: https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried many solution but didn't work. Later I found that there is a **RETAINED APK** is existing in play console release and which has 32 bit. Then I deactivated it and uploaded the new apk & It worked successfully

Answer (score 2):

If you say you "found that there are .so files" I assume your project is not compiling but only using them. You then need this native libraries for the missing architectures from the NDK project which produced this libraries. It can't be done just by a different config in your project.

Comment: Can you give please explain me  "You then need this native libraries for the missing architectures from the NDK project which produced this libraries"

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

Comment: A project which creates a native library (which you are using) produces not only one .so file but several because each architecture needs its own. I can only assume that your .so files are comming from an older project which did not created them for the now required 64bit architectures.

Comment: @georgij The libs that I am using the latest versions and I'm using it

Comment: If you know which library is providing the .so files, look inside (if you can) and check which architectures are present.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add this line ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' (Remove this line)

please add this code in your build.gradle file

-After Release Apk you got 2 file of apk in your release folder

-now you can use app-arm64-v8a-release.apk for playstore release

-I hope this is useful for you

```
android {
lintOptions{
....
}
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk false
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am using bundle abb not apk. In the above case will it work on every devices ? There are 32bit users also using mi application

Comment: reset() method not found in my project

Comment: **hi friend i got another way for build 32 and 64 bit release app or bundle,**

please add this code your build.gradle file

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXXXX"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 237
    versionName "3.3.20"
    multiDexEnabled true

    ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
}

note: remove this functon
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk false
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

**hi friend i got another way for build 32 and 64 bit release app or bundle.**

please add this code your build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.XXXXX"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 29
versionCode 237
versionName "3.3.20"
multiDexEnabled true

ndk {
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
    }
}
```

**note: remove below function**

```
splits {
abi {
    enable true
    reset()
    include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    universalApk false
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Did your app is live ?
2) reset() & include cannot resolve in my studio. Mine Studio is 3.5, project is 3.5.0 & distribution url is 5.4.1.

May I know these details ?

Comment: But reset() & include() not found in my studio. How you done it ?

Comment: remove this code from app gradle

splits {
abi {
    enable true
    reset()
    include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    universalApk false
}
}

Comment: Brother, I didn't using splits { abi { enable true reset() include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' universalApk false } }   in my project.

I'm not undertand what you are saying?